# Automatic Slideshow on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a slideshow with an onload event through a separate JS file. I've tried looking for possible solutions online and all of them require the coding to be all in one file. What would be the best way to approach this issue?

I have attached my HTML coding for the JS reference.

```
     <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/LakeYellowstoneSunset.jpg" height="408px" width="616px"/>
            <div class="text">Yellowstone National Park<div>



            <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/SanMural.jpg" width="408px" height="616px"/>
            <div class="text">San Francisco, CA</div>



            <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/SanJelly.jpg" height="408px" width="616px"/>
            <div class="text">San Francisco Aquarium</div>



            <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/AKGold.jpg" height="408px" width="616px"/>
            <div class="text">Alaska Yukon</div>


            <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/SaltLake.jpg" height="408px" width="616px"/>
            <div class="text">Salt Lake City, UT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _"all of them require the coding to be all in one file"_ I very much doubt that is true. It makes no difference if the code is in the same file or in a .js file. If you show us your code, somebody may be able to help.

Comment: Where's your jQuery and/or JavaScript? You failed to show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking since you didn't give us the JS code you are working with. I am assuming you only want 1 image displayed and we should start cycling through the images after the web pages loads.

I updated your HTML slightly and added JS code to do this in the below codepen/

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WopMzb

I updated your "slide" html to the be wrapped in a div so we can easily hide/show the "slide"

```
<div class="slide active">
   <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
   <img src="images/LakeYellowstoneSunset.jpg" height="408px" width="616px"/>
   <div class="text">Yellowstone National Park<div>
</div>
```

This will only show 1 "Slide" at a time and will change the slide every 3 seconds.

For future questions it may be best to create a codepen or something similar with the CSS/JS/HTML that you are having trouble with. You are more likely to receive a response if it is easier for someone to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked like a charm! I'm sorry I was so vague about my questioning and wrong statements I had. I'm new to this area and trying to do something that is not first nature.

Answer (score 0):

"All of them require the coding to be all in one file". **That's false**. There is no difference, how you include, for example, Javascript code for your HTML:

1. Creating separate js file and include it via `script` tags like this (in your HTML):

   ```
   <script src="yourFile.js"></script>
   ```
2. Or you include all the Javascript logic in your HTML like this:

   ```
   <script>
       // Your Javascript logic here
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Your html structure reminds me of bootstrap's carousel option. If you don't mind adding bootstrap to your project it might be worth a look:

[Bootstrap carousel](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/)

Added bonus is that you don't have to write anything custom for your slideshow control.